# FedEx tracking not working on magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, fedex, shipment-tracking

We're on 2.1.0 Community, but I think this problem has existed since 2.0.
When I try to view tracking on FedEx tracking # (am using an actual live tracking #), I get an error.  Am I doing something wrong, or not doing something?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

- Neither FedEx nor UPS shipping methods are enabled for checkout in the `Store > Configuration` since we're using ShipperHQ extension.
- UPS tracking has no problems.
- UPS tracking works without the shipping method being enabled and without credentials.

As a test, I thought maybe FedEx may require credentials.

So, after applying the FedEx's (production) credential, but shipping method still disabled for checkout, then I get the following error message.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception -0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ActualDeliveryAddress in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php on line 1085

Exception -0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ActualDeliveryAddress in /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php on line 1085
-0 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php(1085): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/var/www/magent...', 1085, Array)
```

Comment: I was unable to include the entire error log, it stackexchange considered  spam.